# BS4: Case sensitive searching

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, case-sensitive

Is it possible to find only those tags which are in upper-case format? I have a html page. There are tags <`a href=..>` and tags `<A href=...>`. I want to get only tags in `<A href=..>` format.

When I try to `all = index.findAll('A')` It returns nothing. 
In case I try `all = index.findAll('a')` I get all tags 'a' and 'A' as well.

Thanks for advices.

Comment: HTML tag names are case-insensitive, so I doubt BeautifulSoup supports this usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML is case insensitive; on parsing all tags are *lowercased*.

If you need to match tags case sensitive, you need to parse the document as XML. Install [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) and tell BeautifulSoup to use that parser in XML mode:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'xml')
```

Note that XML is stricter than HTML; parsing an HTML document that is not adhering to these stricter rules may fail.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was searching for!